# Django querystring transfer from template to view by (input field or anyother tags)

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

How would you transfer tag values to a querystring in an anchor tag in a template ?

For example, suppose I had code in  a template  like this :

## Template

```
<input name="user"><a href=" {% url 'searchsomething'  user %}"><input   type="button"></a></li>
```

## Tried using the name attribute to user pass it along as argument for the namespace but it didn't work.

I want to know how to get values of input tag and put in the `querystring` —which is a namespace as "searchsomething" and it takes one parameter

## urls

```
url(r'^searchsomething/(?P<user>\w*)/$', views.searchsomething, name='searchsomething'),
```

## views

```
def searchsomething(request, user):
    foundMembers =Member.objects.filter(pk=user).values()
    context=RequestContext(request,{'peoplefound':foundMembers})
    template= loader.get_template('social/resultsFound.html')
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Also, I want people to note that I don't want to do it by the usual form method.

Comment: Do you mean try it in the view ? I did try that now but it didn't retrieve the contents from the input tag called "user".

Comment: Another thing I would like to note is that I don't get the anonymous user error.

Comment: You are directly using `user` context in template. Try to be more specific about url argument you want to pass to the url tag. Is it `user.id/pk`, `user.username` or something else that should act as arugment value to the view?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. Are you saying that i should change the arguments in the view function ?

Comment: I've got a solution now and that's to do it with javascript but, surely, you can transfer stuff from tags to querystrings by templates, right?